# select case when isnull('sdas',0)=0 then 'hi' else 'bye' end as 'Value'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below query

```
select case when isnull('23',0)=0 then 'hi' else 'bye' end as 'Value'
```

returns `bye`

BUT

```
select case when isnull('sdas',0)=0 then 'hi' else 'bye' end as 'Value'
```

returns the following Error message in MS-SqlServer2008R2

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'sdas' to data type int.
```

Can you clarify it on which stage it gets conversion has been done

Answer (score 1):

`'23'` can be converted to int on the fly, but `'sdas'` don't.
take string(varchar)-type for all variables:

```
select case when isnull('sdas','0')='0' then 'hi' else 'bye' end as 'Value'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is converting `sdas` to an integer `0`. Instead of using the `isnull` function, you could use the `is null` operator:

```
select case when 'sdas' is null then 'hi' else 'bye' end as 'Value'
```